# colorAccent in Holo Theme

Tags: android, material-design

I used this to change the accent color in **EditText** in the **Material Theme**:

```
<style name="AppThemeSub" parent="@android:style/Theme.Material.Light">
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/colorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

[image: EditText color]

And this to change the **ProgressBar** color:

```
<style name="AppThemeWeb" parent="@android:style/Theme.Material.Light">
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

[image: ProgressBar color]

How I can use this in **Holo Theme**?

PS: I used the **indeterminateDrawable** in the layout of **ProgressBar** and not work with **Holo Theme** devices.

Comment: You have to use one theme at a time ? right ?

Comment: @Arslan I used at value folder the default theme (Holo) and at value-21 folder the Material Theme.

Comment: i think you would have to use appcompat theme. You cannot use colorPrimary etc in holo directly.

Comment: @Arslan What can replace "colorAccent" method in Holo Theme?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the AppCompat theme like this will behave as holo and you can set all material properties here in your value's direcotry style.xml. I have used this theme.

```
//My Customized Theme
<style name="AppTheme"  parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/myPrimaryColor</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/myPrimaryDarkColor</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/myAccentColor</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/myPrimaryTextColor</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/mySecondaryTextColor</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarDivider">@color/myDividerColor</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>

</style>
```

Comment: I use the AIDE for programming and that no have AppCompat Theme (I don't liked the Android Studio)

Comment: @Crimeiaman you do not need Android Studio for AppCompat. All you need is to download the AppCompat Library from the [Android SDK](https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html). (You can scroll down to the end of that page for the SDK **only** (The Standalone SDK does not include Android Studio, so you can continue using your current development environment, and be able to download the AppCompat Support Library.

Comment: Yes you are right .. I suppose i should have added this information in the answer as well. You explained well,

Comment: You nees appcompat support v7 library it is independent of eclipse or android studio,

Comment: @Ankush Oh, ok. Thank you so much